# Getting "Invalid Parameter #10" when attempting to copy folder using robocopy

Tags: robocopy

I'm trying to copy a folder on my internal hard drive to my external hard drive using `robocopy` with the following command:

```
robocopy "source folder" "destination folder" *.* /E /DCOPY:T /COPYALL /LOG:"log folder/log.log" ATTRIB -S -H "destination folder"
```

After running the command, the process stops immediately and I get this error in my log file:

```
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #10 : "-H"
```

I want to remove the hidden and system attributes from all the folders and sub-folders I'm copying. I'm using version XP026 of `robocopy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this Robocopy syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx), Robocopy supplies parameters to do this itself (`/A-:SH`), so you should try those:

```
robocopy "source folder" "destination folder" *.* /E /DCOPY:T /COPYALL /LOG:"log folder/log.log" /A-:SH
```